# Recursive axios.get() returns empty array

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to recursively perform an axios.get() request based on an array of post ids

```
let returnArray = []
post_ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

for (const id of post_ids) {
    axios.get('api/events/' + id)
        .then(response => returnArray = returnArray.concat(response.data))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Event not found: ', error)
            return returnArray
        })
}
return returnArray
```

I know that one of these post ids will be invalid and will return a code 404 from the API.

The problem I am having is that the return array is empty, rather than JSON data of all the valid post id queries (minus the invalid one)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You're not waiting for the async calls to finish before you `return returnArray` at the very bottom

Comment: There's no recursion in your code?

Comment: @Dominik, doesn't the `then()` and `catch()` blocks only trigger once the `get()` has finished though? Isn't this equivalent to `await`?

Comment: That's not what `then` does. An async operation moves the execution to a new thread in node which are not aligned with the main thread. So your bottom return will be in a completely new thread than your async operation. They do not halt for each other unless you put everything inside the `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be actually recursive, you need a *function* that you can call recursively inside the `.then`. But that makes things more complicated than they need to be. How about just `await`ing each call inside the loop?

```
const returnArray = [];
const post_ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
for (const id of post_ids) {
    try {
        returnArray.push(await axios.get('api/events/' + id));
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Event not found: ', id)
    }
}
return returnArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm off the mark with recursion. In any case, this works, but I'm unsure why, mainly because I thought `then()` was equivalent to `await` (because then() would only be triggered once the originating promise is resolved or rejected)

Comment: It does, but `await` halts control flow at the level of the `await`, while `.then` does not (further synchronous code after the `then` will not wait for the Promise to resolve)